# How to properly restore a session on reload using ember simple auth custom authenticator's restore() function?

Tags: authentication, session, ember.js, ember-simple-auth, cookiestore

I have followed this YouTube tutorial on getting started with ember simple auth: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSWN4_EbTPI&t=908s

I have everything working properly except for when refreshing the page. The custom authenticator I am using is supposed to use its `restore()` method on a refresh and grab the user token from the cookieStore, however when my code does this it gets the passed parameter, `data` which is an empty object upon console logging it. It's like it doesn't know to look in the cookieStore to fill out `data` with. I have tried messing with some settings in `config/environment.js` but can't find anywhere online with solid documentation on how to configure simple-auth. I am using v5.0.0

I can see the cookie being created when the app is loaded and filled out when I log in. For reference, here is what it looks like after logging in:

```
ember-simple-auth-session=%7B%22authenticated%22%3A%7B%22authenticator%22%3A%22authenticator%3Atoken%22%7D%2C%22token%22%3A%22secret%20token%22%7D
```

Here it is decoded:

```
{"authenticated":{"authenticator":"authenticator:token"},"token":"secret token"}
```

Here is my custom authenticator - `app/authenticators/token.js`

```js
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class CustomAuthenticator extends Base {
  @service router;
  @service session;

  restore(data) {
    console.log('Restore');
    console.log(data);
    const { token } = data;

    if(token) {
      return data;
    }
    else {
      throw 'no valid session data';
    }
  }

  async authenticate(userData) {
    let response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/users/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(userData),
    });

    if(response.ok) {
      response.json().then((data) => {
        const { token } = data;
        this.session.set('data.token',token);

        console.log(this.session);
        this.router.transitionTo('user', data.id);
      });
    } 
    else {
      let error = await response.text();
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }

  invalidate() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve();
    });
  }
}
```

And this is all I have in `session-stores/application.js`

```js
import CookieStore from 'ember-simple-auth/session-stores/cookie';

export default class ApplicationSessionStore extends CookieStore {}
```

I'm trying to just extract the `token` field from the cookie which by my understanding should be getting passed into `restore(data)` but when I do `console.log(data)` I get `{}` which is just an empty object. If I try `console.log(data.token)` I get `undefined`. What can I try next?